# Replacing several strings in a dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

I am looking for a simple way of replacing several string and assigning it to a new df with the updated replacements

This the the sample column I am working with df['Column']

```
Column
-----------------
K700E
R957Q
Deletion
L747_T751delinsP
S752_I759del
I491M
D770_P772dup
G719A
G735S
N771_H773dup
K467T
E746_T751insIP
D770_N771insD
G724S
K745_A750del
EGFRvIII
V765A
EGFRvII
L858M
```

Some entries contain text which I don't need, basically needs to be cleaned. Below is my code which I can't seem to get right.

```
for i in df['Column']:
df['Column'].replace('Truncating Mutations', '9999')
df['Column'].replace('Amplification', '9999')
print(i)
```

There are also some entries like

```
EGFR-RAD51 Fusion
```

I basically want to remove the word 'Fusion' but keep 'EGFR'.

Any advise is very much appreciated from a novice. =)

Comment: Please elaborate? Why can't you get it right? What's the error?

Comment: Only the first line of the code works. so if you see these 2 lines, df['Column'].replace('Truncating Mutations', '9999') is the only one giving me results. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative answer

---

You can also pass a Dictionary with the key and values you want to replace:

```
rdict = {
    "Truncating Mutations":"9999", 
    "Amplification":"9999",
    "Fusion":""
    }

df[0] = df[0].replace(rdict)
```

Answer (score 2):

`df.replace` is not an in-place operation. Also, you can use `regex=True` and combine the first two replacements. The third can also follow, and is simpler, because you're just removing `Fusion`.

```
df['Column'] = df['Column'].replace('(?:Truncating Mutations)|(?:Amplification)', '9999', regex=True)\
                           .replace('Fusion', '')
```

Once you perform replacement, you assign the result inplace, with `df['Column'] = ...`.

Comment: That work, also was simple. Let me test it a bit more and get back to you